# Rails 3. Cannot validate URLs for http prefix

Tags: validation, ruby-on-rails-3

I am developing an application in Rails 3 and in this application I let the users add URLs to websites. The current problem I am facing is that some of the users forget to include the http or https prefixes which results in a non working link.

Unfortunately there seems to be no way to validate this out of the box?
How can I go about to validate if the submitted URL includes http?

Thankful for all help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a plugin named [validates_url_format_of](https://github.com/henrik/validates_url_format_of/) that seems to work for Rails 3. Otherwise you can write your own [custom validator](http://www.perfectline.co.uk/blog/building-ruby-on-rails-3-custom-validators).

Comment: Thanks! Works fine with the plugin!